# microsoft assessment and planning toolkit alternatives

Tags: linux, open-source

Are there any open source tools which give similar reporting for Linux/Solaris/Unix/Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MAP 5.0 Beta 2 provides heterogeneous server environment reporting for Linux and Windows Server operating systems.  Go here to join the MAP Beta program and download the Beta 2 tool: https://connect.microsoft.com/site297